# Adding a cardan-error to an animation with constraints

Tags: animation, constraints, drivers

I have created an animation of a cardan shaft: [youtube video](http://youtu.be/_SsN2n68sJE). I'm using *transformation constraints* to copy the rotation of the base joint and obviously the others are sliding into each other. I would like to modify the constraints insofar that variations in the rotation-speeds can be simulated. You can download the example from here: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnpq7174evalziw/board.blend.gz)

- **A** I'm using transformation-constraints to simulate a cardan joint. Since transformation constraints can only solve simple linear equations with one variable, it is impossible to correctly calculate the speed inequalities between the joints which would occur in reality. As a result the joints  overlap during the rotation.
- **B** I was looking for a possibility to add functions to emulate this *cardan-error*. I learned recently that it is possible to combine constraints with *drivers*. Blender-drivers call python method. In this methods trigonometric functions can be called and it is possible to use more than one input parameter. (It is necessary to calculate the bend between two joints.)

I would have accepted **B** as solution for my problem.

Comment: You have keyframed the rotation on one object, the others follow that rotation through the constraints you have setup. All you have to do is change the one rotation keyframe to alter the speed.

Comment: @sambler: The rotation speed of the other joints would normally fluctuate (they have a wobbling motion), it would be necessary to add many additional keyframes.

Comment: I found the time to fix the problem:[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8-havK-AME&list=UUZK7PmWl85tQmOdRFsfSvBQ&feature=share). I will add an answer as soon as the question is unlocked.